how to optimize a sql
I'm a beginner in data structures and algorithms, and I'm not sure how to apply them in practice to specific problems. I want to query book_name & user_id, as well as VP and UV, and I've used multi-layer nested subqueries. Although the logic is fine, the time complexity is too high. How should I solve this?
create temporary function exp_ab as 'com.udf.OverseasForuAbExpUDF' using jar 'hdfs://nameservice1/user/hive/udf/dz-ark-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar';
SELECT
    p.book_name AS book_name,p.uv AS UV,q.vp AS VP
FROM 
(SELECT
 ext_map['book_name']  AS book_name,
 COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS uv
FROM dws.dws_clt_video_event_log_simple_hour
WHERE
 dt = '02024061023' AND  exp_ab(user_id, "B552B171", 1000, "15D3271B", 99) = 'foru-base'
GROUP BY
 ext_map['book_name']) AS P
FULL JOIN
(SELECT
 e.book_name,
 COUNT(*) AS vp
FROM
(SELECT
 ext_map['book_name'] AS book_name,user_id,exp_ab(user_id, "B552B171",1000,  "15D3271B", 99) as group_name
FROM dws.dws_clt_video_event_log_simple_hour
WHERE dt = '02024061023' AND  exp_ab(user_id, "B552B171", 1000, "15D3271B", 99) = 'foru-base') AS e
GROUP BY
 e.book_name) AS q
ON P.book_name = q.book_name

I hope to be able to get the results within ten minutes, but I don't know how to operate.
INFO  : 2024-06-11 19:01:48,721 Stage-25_0: 45/45 Finished  Stage-26_0: 1417(+8)/25125  Stage-27_0: 0/25125 Stage-28_0: 0/2199  Stage-29_0: 0/1099  
INFO  : 2024-06-11 19:01:49,723 Stage-25_0: 45/45 Finished  Stage-26_0: 1418(+8)/25125  Stage-27_0: 0/25125 Stage-28_0: 0/2199  Stage-29_0: 0/1099

I understand now, I think my mistake was not performing conditional partitioning, which caused me to query all the data in the table, and now the resources are exhausted, resulting in the error:
Could not connect to hw-gateway-100:10000 (code THRIFTTRANSPORT): TTransportException('Could not connect to hw-gateway-100:10000',)

I understand now, SQL queries themselves do not have a time complexity, but I have consumed a lot of resources due to not limiting the partition; I use limit and where to restrict the queries to a specific day and hour, ext_map is a map-type column in the table, and I am querying in a database under Hive.
here is table structure:



user_id
reqtime
ext_map




First
row
.....


Second
row
.....


....
....
.....



And "book_name" which is contained in the map "ext_map".

SQL and modern database query engines are far removed from undergraduate-level data-structures-and-algorithms courses - I say that because you've convinced yourself of the wrong conclusion ("time complexity"); whereas SQL queries (by themselves) don't have a time-complexity at all (because a query is not an algorithm). The problem lies elsewhere: and is very likely because you're missing INDEX objects and/or have out-of-date STATISTICS on whatever indexes you do have.

Also, you're using LIMIT without an ORDER BY clause - which means you'll get arbitrary rows in any order - that's not useful (I wish all databases would throw an error if LIMIT (aka TOP) is used without an ORDER BY, oh well).

Which RDBMS are you using? Your query looks like portable ISO SQL, except the ext_map['book_name'] syntax, which looks like you're using a wide-column store or in-row JSON blobs, but that isn't Postgres or MySQL's syntax...

Optimization strategies are fairly dependent on the database platform you are using - basically because first your start with an analysis of the actual execution plan created by the database engine for your query (note: it is up the DB to optimize the query, not you directly) ... and doing that is a little different depending on what DB you use. That said, there are "smells" to be avoided - like unnecessary sort operations, returning records that aren't needed. Also see Dai's comments - you have to have some awareness of indexing and other factors that can strongly affect performance.

Please edit original question based on comments from others and this too.  Dont reply via comment... too short.  Please clarify, you are pulling user ID as well as the Ext_map() context -- confirm database and is it a specific function to that database?  Also, the DT = ... Is that some date time context?  Finally edit in your description what it is you are trying to do from simple... I am trying to get for a user, how many other people also... blah, blah, blah.  That might help give context too.

I understand now, SQL queries themselves do not have a time complexity, but I have consumed a lot of resources due to not limiting the partition; I use limit and where to restrict the queries to a specific day and hour, ext_map is a map-type column in the table, and I am querying in a database under Hive.

Please share your table structure and sample data for those tables for us to evaluate how can you optimize you query, and bring results faster.

ok,i got it,then i'll show you my table structure

One of the first points that will help you optimize the performance of SQL queries is to avoid the use of unnecessary subqueries and joins, this can be done even with good data modeling following good practices, such as normalizing the database that is created foreign keys for example.
I see that you are making subqueries and joins on the same table, I believe that the fact that you try to fit everything into the same query or make separate selects will drastically reduce operation time.
Also, there are redundancies in your query, if you can eliminate these redundancies you will certainly perform faster. Hope this helps.
